# Correct bitmap loading in Android regarding patterns and clean code programming

Tags: android, database, design-patterns, bitmap

I am currently working on my first serious android app. It is the first time I am appliying solid patterns programing and design which I learnt during the university studies. I have come across a situation where I dont know the "correct or best" way I should implement it. The problem is as follows:
As you might already know, in Android is not a good idea to keep models with bitmaps as you can easily reach the memory heap. I got a model in my app called "Event". An event has an id, name, description, bitmap etc.. However as I have stated before, when loading events from the database I load every attributes but the bitmap. At the moment, I have got it as a bitmap attribute referencing null with a set and get methods. Thus, my question is, from the point of view of patterns, clean programing, high cohesion and low coupling paradigm etc, how is the best way to retrieve the bitmap from the database? and where should it be retrieved, into the model or when it is required somewhere in the UI (i.e. a listview) ?
Until now I have thought the following solutions:

1.- Lazy loading pattern. Which means to develop the getBitmap inside the event model as a call to the database retreiving the bitmap associated with the event.
    Pros: Very easy to implement; the model knows how to find its own bitmap atribute.
    Cons: High coupling between the database interface and the model; the model shouldnt         have awareness from outside itself; the model wouldnt be a POJO; models shouldnt have complicated methods; many calls to the database (imagine many getBItmap calls).

2.- Getting the model id and calling the database interface from the bussiness logic everytime I need the Bitmap. The model would never have a bitmap referenced from itself.
    Pros: Bussiness logic calls the database interface, low coupling and correct model implementation.
    Cons: Many objects which need the model bitmap should have a database interface reference, increasing copuling between the object and the database interface along the app. Think on an Android listview adapter which needs the bitmap from the event, it should call the database interface which seems kinda ugly. Besides, shouldnt be the own event model responsible to provide its own bitmap?

3.- Your own answer :)

Thank you very much for reading and I ll appreciate your answers.

Explanation of overall architecture:

Activities and the rest of the bussiness logic call a database interface (facade pattern) which I have implemented using Parse analytics API which allows to upload files, images etc as attributes on tables. Thus, if you want to retrieve a bitmap, simply query the parse API (implemented in the facade).
A simple case of bitmap retrieval would be (as I typed before) building the event view for a listview into the adapter, which would need the title, description, **bitmap**, etc of each event loaded.

Comment: Are the bitmaps stored in the database, or do you have paths stored there? If it's just paths this is as easy as setting the path name of the bitmap when you create the Event, and then use the built in bitmap loading mechanisms to have an Event manage it's own image. In the other case I would ask - why are you storing them in the DB? Are you searching over these images?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, just edited to explain it.

Comment: What I would have done would be: Have a simple `Event#getBitmap()` method that loads the bitmap from the db but does not store it inside the model. Now the ui side can e.g. in a listview (and inside some background thread construct) load & cache the bitmap on it's own in a lazy way. Ui does not need to know about the database behind that method.

Comment: Hello zapl, thanks for your answer. I have already got a retrieveBitmap() method in the db intervace.Your are in some way describing my 2nd answer, "calling the database interface from anywhere in the bussiness logic when needed", in this case for a listview would be in the adapter which binds the list to the data in any activity.
The problem with this approach is ,as I typed, that the adapter would need a reference to the database increasing the coupling, which seems ugly (shouldnt be the own model responsible to provide its own image). Anyway looks better than the first approach.

Comment: I'm still unclear where these images are stored - are they actually in the Database, or are they on the filesystem somewhere?  If the later is the case then give events knowledge of where on the Filestystem the image is, do the Event#getBitmap() approach, but instead of going via the database do a file retrieval in the normal way.  This keep your model unaware of the database, managing its own image, and allows you to avoid passing database objects around to other objects.  I'm assuming Event's are available to the object calling loadBitmap().

Comment: To zapl: My mistake, you were talking about the 1st approach, calling the database from the model Event.getBitmap() -> DBInterface.getBitmap(event); which is called "lazy load". However, this approach is not good from the clean code view because the model should be aware of the database which is pretty ugly.
To Nathaniel: Images are stored as files (bit arrays) in a DB which I access using ParseAnalytics API; so I dont have any access to the file path, besides they are on a server, not on the android device. Seems you agree with the 1st approach aswell. Thank you for your answer by the way.